# I need to make an inverse triangle

Tags: java, for-loop, methods

I need to write a program that given a number and a letter it will print the letter as many times as the given number. And after that, i need to call the first method and use the given values to make a triangle.
The first output should be like this if i give it the parameters (5,"u") = "uuuuu"
I have that first part already, but then i need to call that first method and get an output like this:

```
    u

   uu

  uuu

 uuuu

uuuuu
```

This is what i have so far on the code:

```
public class Triangle
{

    private String theLetter;
    private int cnt;
    private String aLetter;
    private int howMany;

    public void getLetters(int cnt, String theLetter)
    {
        System.out.print("\"");
        for(int x=0; x < cnt; x++)
        {
            System.out.print(theLetter);
        }
        System.out.print("\"");
        System.out.println();
    }

    public void getLetterTriangle(int howMany, String aLetter)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < howMany ; i++)
        {
            getLetters(howMany, aLetter);
        }
            System.out.println();
    }
}
```

I just can't get the for loop to do it. Help please.

Comment: Please clarify what the problem is.

Comment: The problem is that I couldn't do the for loop to get the shape of the triangle, but someone already showed me the code, but thanks anyways @Saposhiente

Answer (score -1, accepted):

change your code in getLetters to:

```
public void getLetters(int cnt, int howMany, String theLetter)
{
    System.out.print("\"");
    for(int x=0; x < (howMany-cnt); x++) // you need to display spaces
        System.out.print(" ");
    for(int x=0; x < cnt; x++)
        System.out.print(theLetter);
    System.out.print("\"");
    System.out.println();
}
```

and in getLetterTriangle

```
public void getLetterTriangle(int howMany, String aLetter)
{
    for(int i = 1; i <= howMany ; i++) // start with 1
        getLetters(i, howMany, aLetter); // display i, total width howMany
}
```

Comment: -1: It's homework. Don't spoil. Do not give the plain code. At least give a very thorough explanation.

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux I've placed comments about each changed part, they are enough to understand what the problem was

Answer (score 1):

you should look into this part:

```
for(int i = 0; i < howMany ; i++)
{
    getLetters(howMany, aLetter);
}
```

If you watch closely, you will find that the changing variable in the loop is `i`, not `howMany`. Since this is clearly a homework assignment I leave the rest to you.

Update: you should also look into the answer of Martijn Courteaux. he has a valid point about the spaces in front.

Comment: I know that the problem is in there. I don't know how to make the for-loop to get it done. I've tried to do it, but i can't get it. I even asked some of my friends and still the same. I know i need to try to get it by myself, but there are some things i don't get because what we see in class is not enough information. But thank you anyways.

Comment: Try to understand Lashane's code at least before you present it in class. Really, the best you can do is sit down and think of what the code does line by line. You may also use a debugger to follow the real program flow and the values of the variables.

Answer (score 1):

You are printing a square right now. In your `getLetters()` method, you should have two parts. The first part should print spaces and the second part should print the letter. You will need an extra parameter for your `getLetters()` method, so it can know how many spaces it has to print, before printing the letters.